# Identify SQL Server Version in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-7

I need to identify a SQL Server 7 in TSQL. I tried serverproperty but it's not supported in this version. I have sp_MSGetVersion but it returns a table and I don't know how I can get only the version string from this SP.

Comment: Have you tried `select @@version`?

Comment: Yes but its hard to parse the Version out of this string in SQL

Comment: Check this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) halfway down there is a table with SQLServer 7 version code and SP listed

Comment: Try the `INSERT`/`EXEC` trick (I have no idea if this works in SQL Server 7). Just a note that `sp_MSgetversion` is undocumented/unsupported... but I guess if being on that version of SQL Server isn't a problem, then this won't matter to you.

Comment: That's amazing that you still have SQL Server 7 to play around. I am jealous (sincerely true, no kidding)

Comment: `xp_msver 'ProductVersion'` will help you as well.